# Post request does not work: cannot resolve request parameters is Spring controller class

Tags: spring, controller, http-post

I am building a Spring application and I have a controller that has two methods for Get and Post request. The task of the controller is to show a html form and to get the params that the user has entered. The Get request works fine but Post request does not resolves the params from the html form.

Here is my htmml file with thymeleaf:

```
    <html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="text/html">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Budget Forecast Report</title>
    <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Forecast Report</h2>
        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/forecast/saveInput}" class="form-input" method="post" align="center">
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text"  id="username" name="username" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <p>
                <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Password" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="startDate" class="sr-only">Start date</label>
                <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="StartDate" required>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="endDate" class="sr-only">End date</label>
                <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="EndDate" required>
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class InputFormController {

    private ForecastReportService forecastReportService;

    @Autowired
    public InputFormController(ForecastReportService forecastReportService) {
        this.forecastReportService = forecastReportService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView showForm(Model model) {
        System.out.println("here showForm");
        System.out.println("here showForm");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        model.addAttribute("inputBean", new InputBean());
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(model.asMap());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveInput", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView processInput(
//            @RequestParam("username") String username,
//            @RequestParam("password") String password,
//            @RequestParam("startDate") String startDate,
//            @RequestParam("endDate") String endDate,
                               ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        System.out.println("here processInput");
        System.out.println("here processInput");
        ModelMap modelMap = modelAndView.getModelMap();
        String username = (String) modelMap.getAttribute("username");
        String password = (String) modelMap.getAttribute("password");
        String startDate = (String) modelMap.getAttribute("startDate");
        String endDate = (String) modelMap.getAttribute("endDate");
        modelAndView.setViewName("forecast-success");
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(modelMap);
        try {
            forecastReportService.execute(new InputBean(username, password, startDate, endDate));
        } catch(IOException ioe)  {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

If I have only @RequestParam arguments i the code does not enter  the post method at all and I get exception that says the four parameters: username, password and the two dates are not resolved successfully:

```
"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'username' for method parameter type String is not present
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValueInternal(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:218)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\r\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat 
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
 \r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat 
 org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat 
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat 
 org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat 
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat 
 org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal
 (WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
 \r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
 \r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)\r\n\tat
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n",
    "message": "Required request parameter 'username' for method parameter type String is not present",
```

If I comment the four params and put ModelAndView as input argument the code enters the method but the model map is with null values. I also have InputBean class that is a wrapper for these four strings:

```
    @Component
public class InputBean {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String startDate;

    private String endDate;

    public InputBean() {

    }


    public InputBean(String username, String password, String startDate, String endDate) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

So I tried to do the following too:
`@PostMapping(value = "/saveInput") public String processInput(@ModelAttribute("inputBean") InputBean inputBean) {}`

but this did not worked because Intellij complained that `th:field="*{username}"` is a n error and throws an exception for unsuccessful resolving so I removed it although in internet everywhere people use this syntax.

Could you help me please. Does someone have an idea wehere is the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `InputBean` shouldn't be an `@Component`. If you want to use `th:field` you also need `th:object` in your `<form` tag if not it will error out. Also your form URL doesnt appear to match the controller URL. You should have an `InputBean` as method argument that is annotated with `@ModelAttribute` so that spring can bind the values to it (and properly do the form and input tags for Thymeleaf)>

Comment: Yes, it was with @ModelAttribute("inputBean"), I removed the `@Component` annotation and returned back to the old form of the post method:

`@PostMapping(value = "/saveInput)
public ModelAndView processInput(@ModelAttribute("inputBean") InputBean inputBean, Model model) {
        ... 
modelAndView.setViewName("forecast-success");
        return modelAndView;
    }`

now the code is 500:
`{
  "timestamp": "2021-11-25T13:44:21.416+00:00",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "path": "/saveInput"
}`

Comment: I wonder if even the get request works and that it is not some static page you are rendering. If the parameters aren't there, they aren't there. So there must be something you aren't showing that is throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by implementing the post request the following way:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/index")
    public ModelAndView processUserInput(@ModelAttribute("userInput") UserInput userInput) {
        try {
            validateUserInput(userInput);
            service.execute(userInput);
        } catch(IOException ioe)  {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.put("username", userInput.getUsername());
        modelMap.put("password", userInput.getPassword());
        modelMap.put("startDate", userInput.getStartDate());
        modelMap.put("endDate", userInput.getEndDate());
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(modelMap);
        modelAndView.setViewName("forecast-success");

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

The UserInput (I renamed `InputBean` to `UserInput`) class should be a component, it is not true it shouldn't. After I set the `@Component` again it was resolved successfully.

Respectively, I had to change the GET method too:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/index")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        System.out.println("Invoking the user input form");
        model.addAttribute("userInput", new UserInput());
        return "/index";
    }
```